# How often do business produce income?

Tags: stick-rpg-2

How often do business produce income in [Stick RPG 2](http://www.xgenstudios.com/game.php?keyword=stick-rpg-2)?

I thought it was seven days, but it's obviously longer than that...

Answer (score 2):

It is 14 or 10 or 12 days, but each time you collect them the buget will decrease.

Answer (score 1):

> How often do business produce income in Stick RPG 2?

It is produced after 100 days.